could not find function "str_flatten" with BupaR library
I cloned this repository but, when I execute the following snippet
# Datentransformation (Konvertierung: datatable zu events)
eventlog <- bupaR::activities_to_eventlog(data,
                                          case_id = 'CaseID', 
                                          activity_id = 'Activity',
                                          timestamp = c('Time', 'Time'),
                                          resource_id = 'Resource'
)

I got this error:

Error in str_flatten(str_subset(timestamps,
str_flatten(allowed_lifecycles,  :    could not find function
"str_flatten"

The error also occurs many other times when I work with the BupaR library.
Does anybody have any tips on how to resolve this?
I looked over the web but did not find anything useful at this point.
I am working on this environment:

R version 4.3.1 (2023-06-16)
Platform: aarch64-apple-darwin20 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Sonoma 14.4.1
bupaR_0.5.3


Looks like it belongs to stringr library, load the library https://stringr.tidyverse.org/reference/str_flatten.html , and try again?

You are right! Using the library("tidyverse") on top of the script solved the problem. Thanks!

I'd advise to load only libs that you need.

I would report this as an issue to the authors of the bupaR library.  This shouldn't happen.

Yes, I would report this to the library authors. Personally, is a very good library, but I think that the loading process of data is a really blocker for 90% of possible real world applications. Each problem you solve, generate a new error message to solve...a really nightmare!
